# AngularJS - Lost html after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngroute

I came accross big problem with my simple angular app. After refreshing page, all html is lost!
My problem is not about angular data and/or session/local storage data but only HTML.
For example, when accessing home page via navbar "Home" button it looks like:
[image]

After klicking refresh button or f5 "Home Page" inside h1 tag is lost:
[image]

So the question is - What is wrong with my routing configuration or maybe this is expected behaviour for angular? I was looking a lot about this problem but most of the topics are about saving data in $localStorage or $sessionStorage. This problem occurs for all my pages.

**EDIT**
Hi Guys, thanks for Your comments.

@devqon - I don't think that locationProvider is needed here. I am using routeProvider.
I changed a little bit routing configuration : replaced '' with "" and put otherwise statement at the end of configuration:

```
<code>
app.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl : "src/html/home.html",
        controller  : "HeaderCtrl"
    })
    .when("/home", {
        templateUrl : "src/html/home.html",
        controller  : "HomeCtrl"
    })
    .when("/flights", {
        templateUrl : "src/html/flights.html",
        controller  : "FlightCtrl"
    })
    .when("/customers", {
        templateUrl : "src/html/customers.html",
        controller  : "CustomerCtrl"
    })
    .when("/login", {
        templateUrl : "src/html/login.html",
        controller : "HeaderCtrl"
    })
    .when("/flight_choose", {
        templateUrl : "src/html/flight_choose.html",
        controller : "FlightChooseCtrl"
    }).otherwise("/home");

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('airlinesRequestInterceptor');
});
</code>
```

As You can see I've created HomeCtrl which is very simple:

```
<code>
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function() {});
</code>
```

The home.html is on the first screnshot.
@Gustavo Gabriel - could You be more specific? :)
Aforementioned changes did NOT solve the problem :(

**EDIT 2**

@Kai - thank You for Your response.
After Your advice I changed configuration and now it looks like:
    
    `app.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl : "src/html/home.html",
        controller  : "HomeCtrl"
    })
    .when("/flights", {
        templateUrl : "src/html/flights.html",
        controller  : "FlightCtrl"
    })
    .when("/customers", {
        templateUrl : "src/html/customers.html",
        controller  : "CustomerCtrl"
    })
    .when("/login", {
        templateUrl : "src/html/login.html",
        controller : "HeaderCtrl"
    })
    .when("/flight_choose", {
        templateUrl : "src/html/flight_choose.html",
        controller : "FlightChooseCtrl"
    }).otherwise("/");`

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('airlinesRequestInterceptor');
```

});
    
I've also changed navbar link for Home:
[image]
The problem still occurs, so maybe I misanderstood You.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Michal

Comment: You should include a `$locationProvider.otherwise(..defaultUrl..)` to let angular know if nothing matches, go to the default url (probably home)

Comment: And what does your home.html and HeaderCtrl look like?

Comment: Try $routeProvider.when('', and then put home...

Comment: Hi Guys, I've added EDIT to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, I've created directives for attaching html partials, which didn't work well with routing and ng-view.
As You have seen on my first post, my index.html body looked like:

```
<code>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ng-header></ng-header>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
        <ng-footer></ng-footer>
    </div>
</body>
</code>
```

I just wanted to have my index.html as simple as possible. I've created html files for header, content, footer and directives for injecting them.
For example, directive for content looked like:

```
<code>
app.directive('ngContent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: '/src/html/content.html'
  }
});
</code>
```

When I changed above directive to this one, problem with loosing html after refreshing page disappeared :

```
<code>
app.directive('ngContent', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div id="content">'+
    '<div ng-view></div>'+
    '</div>'
  };
});
</code>
```

After digging a little bit, I found there was an issue for angular team for that scenario and there is simple solutions for that:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6812

According to what @jswright and @saidimu wrote:

> if ng-view instantiation is delayed (through ng-include) then the $route instantiation is delayed as well. This means that $route will miss the location change event.
>
> Fix:
>   Run $route update function on instantiation (not just on the location change event)

So in order to fix this issue You have to only inject $route into run function.

```
<code>
app.run(['$route', function($route)  {

}]);
</code>
```

I found interesting post about $route :

[$route Must Be Injected In Order To Enable The $routeChangeSuccess Event In AngularJS](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2770-route-must-be-injected-in-order-to-enable-the-routechangesuccess-event-in-angularjs.htm)

Once again,
Thank You Guys for help.

Answer (score 1):

Your inclusion of the `HeaderCtrl` in your Routes is causing problems, as you're specifying two controllers for the same /home path. Change the `controller` for `.when ("/"` to `HomeCtrl`, and just specify the `HeaderCtrl` in your HTML for the Header as an attribute, `ng-controller="HeaderCtrl"`. I've made the same mistake before.

Comment: Hi, I've added an Edit.

Comment: Try changing your .otherwise to look like `.otherwise({
   redirectTo: '/'
  });`

Comment: Hi Kai, I will post an answear in some minutes. I've found the solution and it was NOT related with routing configuration but my misunderstanding of directives :O

Comment: Glad you figured it out.